# FFMPEG command error for scene detection: Output file is empty

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I'm trying to detect scenes in a given video and after playing around with  `scenecut` thresholds, store the first frame of each scene as an image.

I'm using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "select=gt(scene\,0.5), scale=640:360"
 -vsync vfr yosemiteThumb%03d.png
```

But it shows me an error:

```
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Simplest guess: no two consecutive frames are more than 50% different. If you generated the full dump of scene scores then check what the typical scores are for manually identified scene changes.

Comment: You are right Gyan. I get something when I set it to `0.1`. I wish there could be some ways ffmpeg to set threshold automatically to get exactly X number of photos!

Comment: @Gyan: Perhaps this warrants a separate question, but how exactly would you produce such a dump? This would be useful not only to inspect the typical values of scene scores, but also to select the threshold for scene detection later (without having to process the video again) by processing the dump.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40689366